# Is dialogue procedurally generated?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I made an effort to learn a lot of words to be able to communicate with the Korvax, but I'm noticing that even though my character understands all of the words, they're not perfectly coherent or grammatically correct by a longshot. For instance, a Korvax NPC asked me:

> ahem. korvax entity help?

[image]

Is the grammatical structure like this because dialogue is procedurally generated, or is there a special piece of equipment/milestone I need to acquire in order to improve translation?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to decipher the meaning from the words you are able to translate. In this case, "korvax entity help?" is a rough translation of "Can I help you?" That said, I *think* they just spew predetermined phrases at you, really.

Comment: if it's procedurally generated then it's only done at the very start of the game once to make the language unique each playthought. one of the things you do in the game is translate what they are saying which is totally pointless if all speech is procedurally generated

Comment: Something also tells me that the devs didn't give a hoot about proper English grammar; they are aliens with their own dialect and rules, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Dialog **is** procedurally generated but not in the same sense that the planet or and structures or fauna and wildlife are 'procedurally generated.' 
In the context you're asking - yes, all evidence points to that it is but other courses of information decrease the depth that procedures exist.

Syntax is procedural within a limit, structure is procedural and identical for all members of the same race, game-wide; dialect between races will change game to game. Their common bond is a predefined dictionary.

Your image example "Ahem. Korvak entity help?" will always translate to this from the original words by the Korvak.

Nicholas Tan's [blog post](http://www.gamerevolution.com/features/so-there-are-about-400-words-in-no-man-skys-alien-language) on GameRevolution claims he's discovered that only a little more than 400 words total exist between the three races and Atlas. Additionally, a few online translators exist like [this one](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Gek_(language)) for the Gek.

But no milestone or other item in the game corrects the grammar to something to doesn't feel jerky and procedural generation isn't necessarily the cause of what you see, rather it seems to be just how the races were written by design.

Comment: Are you sure it's procedurally generated? When I last played (at launch, more or less), I kept getting the same quests over and over. Since I spent almost all my time in a single species' system, I learned almost all of their words pretty quickly, and the quest dialogue was always the same for identical quests - there was no variation. If the dialogue was procedural, I'd expect at least a handful of differences.

Comment: The dialog when speaking to aliens is what I took the questions to mean, but if it was a more borad question concerning machine output and every dialog point then only some of it is